# Windows PKZIP encryption / compression calls might be altering password?

Tags: windows, decompilation, dll, decompress

I have a DLL with the following code which decrypts and decompresses an old PKZip 2.0 file...

```
basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >3;
basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >* ptr3 = <Module>.to_string(&basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >3, sPassword);
<Module>.addUNZIP_Decrypt(<Module>.std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >.c_str(ptr3));
<Module>.addUNZIP_Overwrite(11);
<Module>.addUNZIP_InstallCallback(<Module>.__unep@?zip_callback@?A0xb8f18585@@$$FYGHFFPAD@Z);
<Module>.addUNZIP_View(0);
```

ptr3 is the pointer to the password string.  What's strange is that the prior line has the password, but the password doesn't work when I try to unzip the file manually with 7Zip, WinRAR, or PKZip.  ...yet the program does it successfully.

Is it possible the ZIP/UNZIP calls are modifying the password (like adding an unprintable 00 to the end or something)?

Comment: You can use a tool like *[signsrch](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm#signsrch)* on the executable, to get further insights on the compresion/encryption algorithm used.

Comment: Does that password contain any unusual characters, or is it limited to a usual set of alphanumerics?

Comment: The password is 10 latin alpha-numeric chars.  I tried running a brute force on the archives, but it doesn't recognize the password, or anything similar.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible the ZIP/UNZIP calls are modifying the password

Yes, it's possible that `<Module>.addUNZIP_Decrypt()` modifies the password, or draws a giraffe on your screen, or plays The Star Spangled Banner out through your speakers.

You need to reverse engineer the function to determine what it does.

Comment: This module is Stephen Darlington's original PKZip library 0.69.  I doubt he's drawing a giraffe.  Let me see if the source is public...

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the source is still private despite being written in 1995.  In any case, I cannot imagine that the addZip module modifies the password.  I'm leaning towards the possibility that the file format is somehow not compatible with modern compression programs.